# String replace not working with value returned from a XMLHttpRequest request

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel, output-buffering

I have a (Laravel) PHP code that returns a long string in this way:

```
echo json_encode([
    'created' => $count,
    'total' => $num_stores,
    'progressValue' => round((100 / $num_stores) * $count, 2),
    'token' => str_repeat('|',1024*64)
]);
```

I need to get this string in javascript and clean it, removing all "|" character. But it seems not working.

This is my javascript code:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    try {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            alert('[XHR] Done');
        } else if (xhr.readyState > 2) {
            var new_response = xhr.responseText.substring(xhr.previous_text.length);
            var cleanedResponse = new_response.replace(/[|]/g, '');

            console.log('CLEANED RESPONSE: ' + cleanedResponse);
            var result = JSON.parse( cleanedResponse );
            console.log('AFTER THE PARSE');

            xhr.previous_text = xhr.responseText;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
        alert("[XHR STATECHANGE] Exception: " + e);
    }
};
xhr.open("POST", "...", true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
xhr.send(params);
```

I always get the exception when I try to parse JSON, and in the console I still see the "|" characters in the "cleanedResponse" variable.

How is it possible if I replace them?

Answer (score 0):

When `xhr.readyState == 3`, then `xhr.responseText` holds only partial data - 3 means that the response has not yet been fully downloaded. You probably try to parse only partial JSON string that is not complete and therefore not valid and parsable. Wait for downloading complete response (`xhr.readyState == 4`) and then try to clean and parse JSON.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState for further explanation of XHR states.

Comment: I need to parse the partial data, I need to implement a progressbar. When I am at state == 4 the process is over.

Comment: Sure, you can do it. Change progress bar in state > 2, but don't do `JSON.parse` until the string is fully loaded, and that's when state == 4.

Comment: Also, XHR has a special event that fires when a piece of data is downloaded and gives you numbers about how much is loaded and how much remains to be loaded. It is meant especially for situations like yours. You won't need to measure length of responseText. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress for more

Comment: xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(p) { console.log("Loaded " + p.loaded + " of " + p.total); });